# Наложение картинок в php

Tags: php, изображения

Есть две картинки, нужно чтобы при виводе первой картинки на нее наложилась вторая автоматически. пробовал вот так но не работает.

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('label-1.jpg');
$stamp = imagecreatefromjpeg('img-label.jpg');

imagecopy($im, $stamp,  0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp) );

echo ' <img src="label-1.jpg">';
```

Видел в интернете вот такой вариант.

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('label-1.jpg');
$stamp = imagecreatefromjpeg('img-label.jpg');

imagecopy($im, $stamp,  0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp) );
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
```

Он рабочий но не подходит так как на странице присутствуют не только картинки.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы загружаете картинку, вы создаёте её представление в памяти и работаете именно с ним, а не с файлом. После копирования одного на другое результат надо сохранить. Функция `imagejpeg` умеет записывать результат в файл, для этого ей надо передать второй аргумент -- путь к файлу. После того как вы сохраните файл, вы можете ссылаться на него в теге `img`.

```
$newImgPath = __DIR__ . '/imgWithLabel.jpg';
imagejpeg($im, $newImgPath);

echo '<img src="' . htmlspecialchars($newImgPath) . '">';
```

Comment: imagejpeg($im, 'label-1.jpg'); Добавил эту строку, картинка не выводиться на екран, что не так?

Comment: @ПетроЧайківський проверьте сохранился ли файл, если сохранился, то скорее всего веб-сервер просто не имеет доступ к картинке по пути указанному в img.

Comment: Как после того как картинка вывелась на екран удалить ее?

Comment: Удалять картинку на которую указывает src тэга img -- не очень хорошая идея. Если картинка нужна только для вывода на экран один раз, можно не сохранять файл а записать в src непосредственно данные изображения data:image/jpeg;base64 (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL) или использовать javascript и сделать наложение в браузере.